# Windows 7 IIS can not be turned on

Tags: windows, iis, windows-7

I'm trying to Turn on IIS Server on my 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate installed notebook. But when I try to it on via ***Turn Windows Features on and off *** the progress bar is filling till the end and the computer is just locked. I can not do anything but restatring the computer with power button. And of course it is not enabled.  Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/installation-issues/troubleshooting-iis-7x-installation-issues

Please do some troubleshooting following Microsoft's article. I think CBS cache on this machine is broken, and the article shows how to identify the problem and get it fixed.